# Google Play Games

Tags: applications, google, google-play-games, lagging

For me and my friends the Google Play Games App always laggs whenever you're trying to view achievements. Since we all have a Nexus 5X, I can't get any feedback whether it is a common problem.

I am wondering, does anybody have the same issue? It is rather annoying that whenever I want to look at my achievements, I can't because of the lagg

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a problem with the Play Games app itself.

I have encountered this issue, too, and it looks like the app loads images in its main (UI) thread. This means, that this thread won't be able to render frames until the image is ready. As processing those images takes long time to finish, some frames will be skipped. This will result in laggish effect.

So, all we can do is wait for Google to fix this issue.